# Setting Infinity as default in django range fields with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django now supports officially postgres range fields. How can i specify Infinity as default upper limit in one of these.

1. Ideal would be to use (default=Inf) or something like this as argument to the field definition in the model.
2. If not, at least something by overriding model.clean while saving.

It is not a good solution to assume a really high value and use it as a default. That assumption might break anytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to set Infinity as upper bound. If you set upper bound to `None` it will be treated as unbound value i.e. no limit at at all.

Django Range Fields use [`psycopg2 Range objects`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-range) and from its documentation:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `lower` – lower bound for the range. `None` means unbound
>
> `upper` – upper bound for the range. `None` means unbound